# How to forward a class instance to dependent files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrency

I have searched many hours for an answer to this, and have not found one that directly answers my problem. So, bear with me if you found it within your first Google search.

Say FileClass.py is:

```
# Assume there is programming to make it thread-safe and use the queue to write to the file.
class FileWrapper:
    def__init__(self, filename):
        self.file = open(filename, 'w')
        self.queue = Queue()

    def write(self, text): ...
```

And there are two files, `DependentA.py` and `DependentB.py`, that import this class to write to `example.txt`. This would create two instances of `FileWrapper` that would write to the file at the same time, corrupting the data and defeating the purpose of it.

I was wondering if it was possible to check if an existing instance of `FileWrapper('example.txt')` and forward that instance instead of creating a new one. Or somehow, create a server-client model where `FileWrapper` is the server and dependent files are the clients.

I believe a similar, if not the same, concept is Django's `Persistent Connections`.

Comment: Are `DependentA.py` and `DependentB.py` running in the same Python interpreter (as part of the same project)? Or do you run them separately as scripts in different, but concurrently running Python interpreters?

Comment: I don't completely understand what you're saying, however `DependentA.py` and 
@halloleo `DependentB.py` are run separately, but are part of the same overall project (By project, I mean they work towards a singular goal, but can't be put into the same file). I believe Django has something similar with their databases, called `Persistent Connections`.

Comment: So you have two separate scripts you run at the same time and they both write to `example.txt`. You could have a global block as long one script writes to the file. Anyway, what to you want to achieve/avoid? Maybe flesh out your sample in the post a bit more...

Comment: I'll fix it in the morning.